# Computing a complex integral over a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say I have $\int_{C[0, 3]} \frac{dz}{z^2-6z-27}$

I'm working ahead in my text and I don't trust myself with some of this stuff yet.  Here's how I started the problem:

Firstly: $\int_{C[0, 3]}\frac{dz}{z^2-6z-27} = \int_{C[0, 3]}\frac{dz}{(z-9)(z+3)} =  \int_{C[0, 3]}\frac{dz}{12(z-9)} -  \int_{C[0, 3]}\frac{dz}{12(z+3)}$

Here's where I'm not sure about things.  I can proceed by just parametrizing my circle and using e definition of integration over a path?

Comment: There's a non-removable singular point of the function *on* the integration path: how can you integrate that?

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! You can get displayed equations by using double instead of single dollar signs. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Indeed, -3 lies on my circle.  What can I do about it?  I did not reach Cauchy's integral formula yet.  If I had that it would be applicable and easy to do.